# Django Facebook Social-Plugin loads before template tag

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

Very odd~

Basically I have a standard "Like!" button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="myURL/things/{{MyINFO}}/" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Over at views.py I have:

```
def myView(request):
    #Other things
    ctx = {
            'MyINFO' : MySTRING,
            'Otherstuff'  : Otherstuff
            }
    return render_to_response('myApp/myPage4.html', ctx, RequestContext(request))
```

When the user "Like"s the page, they should be liking `myURL/things/MyString/` but they are getting `myURL/things/%7B%7BMyINFO%7D%7D/`

Could the facebook stuff be loaded before the template is pre-processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woops, the front-end person changed the {{}} to {{}}

That is, `{{}} to &#123;&#123;&#125;&#125;`

:)